# How do I get the total price of all the items in the basket

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I get the total price of all the items in the basket?

I want to get the total price of all the items in the cart after adding items in the cart. The price should also increase when the quantity of each item is increased and also decrease when the quantity is decreased. Please help me with that,

The total variable in the cart class outputs null

The cart class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'dish_object.dart';

class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Dish> _cart;
  Cart(this._cart);

  @override
  _CartState createState() => _CartState(this._cart);
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  _CartState(this._cart);
  List<Dish> _cart;

  double totalPrice = 0;

  double getTotalPrice() {
    double total = 0;
    _cart.forEach((item) {
      total += item.totalPrice;
    });
    setState(() {
      totalPrice = total;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getTotalPrice();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cart'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.send_rounded),
              tooltip: "Confirm Order",
              onPressed: () {
                if (_cart.isNotEmpty) {
                  setState(() {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "Order Confirmed",
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0);
                  });
                }
                if (_cart.isEmpty) {
                  setState(() {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "Cart Empty",
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0);
                  });
                }
              }),
          if (_cart.length > 0)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 10.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text(
                  _cart.length.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 12.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _cart.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var item = _cart[index];
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 2.0),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: ListTile(
                //Leading
                leading: Text(item.totalPrice.toString() +
                    item.category +
                    "\n" +
                    "R" +
                    item.price.toString()),

                //Title
                title: Text(item.brandName +
                    "\n" +
                    "(" +
                    item.counter.toString() +
                    ")"),
                //Subtitle
                subtitle: GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      item.incrementCounter();
                    });
                  },
                ),

                //Trailing
                trailing: GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.remove_circle,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      item.decrementCounter();
                    });
                  },
                ),
                isThreeLine: true,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a variable _totalPrice and accessing that

```
    double _totalPrice = 0;
```

which can be changed by one general function:

```
double getTotalPrice() {
    double total = 0;
    _cart.forEach((item) {
      total+= item.totalPrice;
    });
    setState(() {
        _totalPrice = total;
       });
  }
```

*add getTotalPrice() to your initState() function, so it gets called when the screen is mounted or somewhere else in your code.*

**or** increase/decrease the total value every time a product is added/deleted

```
  _addPrice(double price) {
       setState(() {
        _totalPrice += price;
       });
    }

_subtractPrice(double price) {
       setState(() {
        _totalPrice -= price;
       });
    }
```

--
edit: And make sure to insert the variable wherever in your view you want to show it

Comment: where do i declare the _totalPrice Variable?

Comment: below  your other variable declarations, in this case that's below List<Dish> _cart;

Comment: is there something that I should do in the Dish class?

Comment: I don't think thats necessary. Have you tried adding _totalPrice whereever in your code you want to display it, and adding the method getTotalPrice() I mentioned above in your initState() method?

Comment: yes and I get an error of undefined name on the total variable

Comment: I edited my answer above, it should be double total = 0; I also changed int's in my answer to double's since you will most likely be having decimal numbers

Comment: now my initState function throws an error, ive edited my question with my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225527/discussion-between-kimeuvade-and-lefentse-mphahlele).

Answer (score 0):

`cartTotalPrice()` doesn't really do much except for keeping the total price locally. And it's never called. Declare the total variable outside and wrap the for each body in `setState()` or just return it from the method. Don't forget to reset the total variable after adding a new item to the _cart or simply just add the new items price to the total.